CAP: Unable to fetch the entity fields of a composite entity in com.sap.cds.ql.Predicate via CQL query
I have a db entity called ComplaintTypeConfigurations as shown below.
entity ComplaintTypeConfigurations : cuid, managed {
    identifier                       : DataType.Identifier;
    complaintCategory                : ComplaintCategory;
    code                             : DataType.Code;
    description                      : localized DataType.Description;
    individualComplaintType          : DataType.Flag default false;
    itemCategory                     : ItemCategory;
    complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings : Composition of many ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings
                                           on complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.complaintTypeConfiguration = $self;
    numberRange                      : NumberRange; //deprecated
    isActive                         : Boolean default true;
    currentNumber                    : DataType.CurrentNumber; //deprecated
}

Here we have a composite relation to complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings which has salesOrganization, distributionchannel and division fields under it as shown below.
entity ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings : cuid, managed {
    salesOrganization          : SalesOrganization;
    distributionChannel        : DistributionChannel;
    division                   : Division;
    complaintTypeConfiguration : ComplaintTypeConfiguration;
}

Now I would want to query the sales/distribution/division using predicates as shown below.

        Predicate predicateSalesArea = CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.SALES_ORGANIZATION_ID).eq(salesOrganization)
                .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_ID).isNull()
                        .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.DIVISION_ID).isNull()))
                .or(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.SALES_ORGANIZATION_ID).eq(salesOrganization)
                        .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_ID).eq(distributionChannel)
                                .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.DIVISION_ID).isNull())))
                .or(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.SALES_ORGANIZATION_ID).eq(salesOrganization)
                        .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_ID).eq(distributionChannel)
                                .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.DIVISION_ID).eq(division))));
        
        Predicate predicate = CQL.get(ComplaintTypeConfigurations.IS_ACTIVE).eq(true)
                  .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeConfigurations.COMPLAINT_CATEGORY_CODE).eq(complaintCategoryCode))
                  .and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeConfigurations.COMPLAINT_TYPE_TO_SALES_AREA_MAPPINGS).isNull()).or(predicateSalesArea);
        
    if(code!=null || description!=null) {
            
            predicate.and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeConfigurations.CODE).contains(code).and(CQL.get(ComplaintTypeConfigurations.DESCRIPTION).contains(description)));
        }
            
            
        CqnSelect select=Select.from(ComplaintTypeConfigurations_.class)
                        .columns(a->a.ID(),b->b.code(),c->c.description(),
                                e->e.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().salesOrganization_ID(),
                                f->f.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().distributionChannel_ID(),
                                g->g.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().division_ID(),
                                h->h.individualComplaintType(),
                                i->i.itemCategory_ID()).where(predicate);

filteredResult=db.run(select);

When I run this query I get error as below.
No element with name 'salesOrganization_ID' in 'CustomerConfigurationService.ComplaintTypeConfigurations' (service 'PersistenceService$Default', event 'READ', entity 'CustomerConfigurationService.ComplaintTypeConfigurations')
    at com.sap.cds.services.impl.ServiceImpl.dispatch(ServiceImpl.java:256) ~[cds-services-impl-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cds.services.impl.ServiceImpl.emit(ServiceImpl.java:177) ~[cds-services-impl-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cds.services.ServiceDelegator.emit(ServiceDelegator.java:33) ~[cds-services-api-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cds.services.utils.services.AbstractCqnService.run(AbstractCqnService.java:53) ~[cds-services-utils-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cds.services.utils.services.AbstractCqnService.run(AbstractCqnService.java:43) ~[cds-services-utils-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.sap.ic.cmh.configuration.persistency.ComplaintTypeConfigurationDao.getAllComplaintsWithWildCharacter(ComplaintTypeConfigurationDao.java:179) ~[classes/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

I am unable to fetch the composite entity fields,How can I achieve this using predicates.
Can anybody please help me here?
However I can achieve this using CQN query as shown below.
        filteredResult = db
                .run(Select.from(ComplaintTypeConfigurations_.class)
                        .columns(a->a.ID(),b->b.code(),c->c.description(),
                                e->e.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().salesOrganization_ID(),
                                f->f.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().distributionChannel_ID(),
                                g->g.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().division_ID(),
                                h->h.individualComplaintType(),
                                i->i.itemCategory_ID())
                        .where(d->d.isActive().eq(true).and(d.complaintCategory_code().eq(complaintCategoryCode).and(d.code().contains(code).or(d.description().contains(description))).and(not(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().exists())
                                .or(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().salesOrganization_ID().eq(salesOrganization)
                                        .and(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().distributionChannel_ID().isNull()
                                                .and(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().division_ID().isNull())))
                                .or(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().salesOrganization_ID().eq(salesOrganization)
                                        .and(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().distributionChannel_ID().eq(distributionChannel)
                                                .and(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().division_ID().isNull())))
                                .or(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().salesOrganization_ID().eq(salesOrganization)
                                        .and(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().distributionChannel_ID().eq(distributionChannel)
                                                .and(d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().division_ID().eq(division))))))));

But for my scenario, I would need to modify the query as per certain conditions, hence using above query I end up having multiple if else block with almost same query with slight modification of fields. Hence, we decided to go with predicates. But we are unable to achieve this.

Based on the error message, it looks like there is a level missing in the predicate. Based on the error message, the field named salesOrganization_ID is searched for in ComplaintTypeConfigurations, which is actually in ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings. If I look at the CQN query you shared, it shows that salesOrganization_ID is searched for in ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings: d.complaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings().salesOrganization_ID(). So the query is for the ComplaintTypeConfigurations_.class, but you have to go one level down.
If you look at the Java documentation for CQL.get, there are two types of parameterization that I think you could use. One is with the String parameter, where you separate element names with a dot, or where you can pass a list to it. I haven't tried it yet, but I'm thinking something like this:
CQL.get(ComplaintTypeConfigurations.COMPLAINT_TYPE_TO_SALES_AREA_MAPPINGS + "." + ComplaintTypeToSalesAreaMappings.SALES_ORGANIZATION_ID)
Could you try it out maybe?
